# Entity Framework: using the same instance of the model across methods?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm working on an application the consumes a web service and pushes the data directly to a SQL Server 2008 database via EF4. I need to break up the process of pulling down data from the WS, updating records in SQL, and deleting records in SQL that no longer exist in the WS, because the WS itself can be pretty flaky at times and it's proven simpler and easier to troubleshoot if I use separate methods to handle retrying certain steps than to try to cram it all into a single method.

My question is this: when I create an instance of the model (MyEntities context = new MyEntities()), can I pass it to the other methods so that I avoid issues with two different instances trying to update the database at different and overwriting each other? If the answer is yes, how should I do it?

I'm thinking that I should add it as an argument with the ref keyword, a la:

```
MyEntities context = new MyEntities();
CallSomeOtherMethod(ref context, otherinfo);

internal static void CallSomeOtherMethod(ref MyEntities entity, String[] otherinfo)
{
    entity.DoSomething();
...
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no need for `ref`, this would only be needed if you plan to **replace** the context to another one inside the method.

Second, think at the class level, you are in object-oriented world. This means that you don't pass db context to individual methods but rather - to classes that have their specific responsibility.

```
public class SomeService
{
    private DbContext _context;

    public SomeService ( DbContext ctx )
    {
        this._context = ctx;
        ...
    }

   // now, context is available for all methods inside the class
```

and then

```
   // pass existing context
   SomeService service = new SomeService( context );
```